# Extracting texts using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have the below string in a file. I am trying out regex to extract the paragraphs after "---" which is not shows as a text in this editor. The image below should give you an understanding of text.

```
( 2021-07-10 01:24:55 PM GMT )STEMAILTE
---
Badminton is a racquet sport played using racquets to hit a shuttlecock across
a net. Although it may be played with larger teams, the most common forms of
the game are "singles" (with one player per side) and "doubles" (with two
players per side).


( 2021-07-10 01:27:55 PM GMT )ARAMASU
---
Both the academies run a residential training program for upcoming and
talented footballers and Boxers. The Academies are functioning in Sarusajai
Sports complex.
```

Have attached the image below -

[image: captured_img]

So far I have tried

```
re.findall(r'([(){}[\]][^\S]\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [a-zA-Z]{2} [a-zA-Z]{3}[^\S][(){}[\]][\w.]+)(\n-+)((\n.+))+',text)
```

which just gives me the datetime and text after that.

I am trying to extract the three pharagraphs after the "---" in each groups from the above image. There are garbage texts above the provided ones here.

Comment: If the pattern will be same will thi work: `data = text.split('---')`

Comment: I get your point in capturing just the texts. Still, that is not getting extracted using re.findall which is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you wanna use such a complex regex for this kinda simple task? Is there any variable separation needed or does your text have always have the same structure?
If so, why not using something like this:

```py
paragraph = text.splitlines()
paragraph = [line for line in text.splitlines() if not (line.startswith("---") or line.startswith("(") or not line)]
print(paragraph)
```

assuming your text is stored in a variable called `text`.

Comment: The reason I'm going with regex is that the text contains other random strings, table above the text provided here.